# Is there a way to display user comments on a intranet webpage and load it again when logged in?

Tags: html, comment-system

I have a requirement where I need to maintain a sheet:

1. I want users to log in into the intranet hosted web page(no login creds required, just a basic form page), where they add their comments and the comments should be displayed right below.
2. Also the comments should be appended to an offline sheet possibly from where the data is being displayed to the web page, which I can rotate monthly(manually is fine)
3. I could do this using HTML & JavaScript but I am not well versed in either. I used the code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <center>
  <head lang="en">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script language="JavaScript">
    function showInput() {
        document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = 
                    document.getElementById("user_input").value;
    }
  </script>

  </head>
<body>
<center>
  <form>
    <label><b>Enter your task updates:</b></label>
    <input type="text" name="message" id="user_input">
  </form>

  <input type="submit" onclick="showInput();"><br/>
  <label>Comments: </label>
  <p><span id='display'></span></p>
</body>
</html>
```

But as soon as the page is reloaded the data is gone (obviously). I need this to be strictly offline and simple.
Any open-source software or rectification for code would be really appreciated.

Comment: Apologies seems the code got executed in the question, I wan't expecting that: Please check the code here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15447889/display-html-form-values-in-same-page-after-submit Answered by ojonugwa ochalifu